# Non-bash equivalent to "trap ERR"

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to remove some bashisms from a shell script.

I can't figure out how I would replicate 'trap ERR': ERR is not a signal, and is not in the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_28), but is a common bashism (see e.g. [the LDP guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)).

How do I replicate `trap ERR` in a standards-compliant `/bin/sh` script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a combination of `set -e` and `trap ... EXIT`.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

err_handler () {
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && exit
    # Code for non-zero exit status here
}

trap err_handler EXIT
```

`set -e` will cause the script to exit whenever an unguarded command has an non-zero exit status. The error handler will be called unconditionally when the script exits, but inside the handler you can simply exit if the current exit status is 0, i.e., we reached it without any errors occurring.

By "unguarded" command I mean a command that isn't run in a context where a non-zero exit status is reasonably expected to occur, such as in the condition for an `if` statement.

Comment: Must notice the difference. `ERR` has the registered command executed every time when an error occurs, but it doesn't make the script exit, while `set -e` does.

Answer (score 1):

ERR is not really a signal. See: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bourne_Shell_Scripting/Debugging_and_signal_handling#Err..._ERR.3F at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: That really doesn't answer my question. I know it's not a signal. I want to know how to replicate the behaviour in a standards-compliant way. ERR isn't standards compliant, as the bottom of your screen shot shows.

Comment: @dja: That's the point. There's no portable equivalent. Verify $? after each operation manually.

Comment: Ok, well that's disappointing. You could probably make that an answer rather than a comment, then I could potentially accept it, if no-one figures out a way in the next couple of days.

Comment: It's an answer now, so be my guest -- I'm so close to 1,000 reputation points :-)